# Can i hide Bill of Materials menu for 1 user?

Tags: openerp-7

i want to hide  **Manufacturing ==> Bill Of Materials** form a specific user. can i do that in view part by inheriting Menuview?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can hide by using security groups. Create one group and include all other users except this user. Then goto "**Settings >> Technical >> User Interface >> Menu Items**". Then choose "Bill of Materials" and add the new group created. Now it will be hidden for the other user.

To do it in xml of your custom module, inherit the action "**mrp_bom_form_action**" and menu item with id "**menu_mrp_bom_form_action**" from mrp. add groups attribute to the menu item and give the newly created group.